# How to Create a Collapsible Hamburger Menu Icon Custom Inspector/Editor Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I saw this custom inspector icon in a video recently and I think it could be very useful for a custom Editor I am creating at the moment. I have not been able to find any info about how to creat it though, so I was wondering if anyone knew how, or if it might have been something that the video creator added himself.

[image]

The Item boxed in red is what I am looking to create. If anyone has any information on how it is created or how one might go about created it from scratch I would much appreciate it.

Comment: More context please. Does this embed directly into the unity program, or is it part of the scene?

Comment: Please share your custom editor code?

Comment: @TylerSigi This would be part of a unity custom editor (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) they are used to add functionality to components &/or change how they are displayed.

Comment: @killer_mech I do not have any custom editor code atm because I do not know how to create this "display item" (the collapsible hamburger menu). (sorry for the double reply I do not know how to @ two people)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create this image by using a GUIStyle.

```
using UnityEditor;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(MyProperty))]
public class MyPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    //which index of the popupOptions you want selected
    private int selectedIndex = 0;

    //the different options you want to display when the Popup is selected
    private readonly string[] popupOptions =
        { "Option One", "Option Two" };  

    private GUIStyle popupStyle;

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        //stuff above here

        if (popupStyle == null)
        {
            popupStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.GetStyle("PaneOptions"));
            popupStyle.imagePosition = ImagePosition.ImageOnly;
        }
        EditorGUI.Popup(position /*or whatever position you want*/, selectedIndex, popupOptions, popupStyle);

        //stuff below here
    }
}
```

Found [here](https://github.com/roboryantron/Unite2017/blob/master/Assets/Code/Variables/Editor/FloatReferenceDrawer.cs).